# using threads for the first time

Tags: c, pthreads

//trying to make each thread print its thread number not id and then print a message from the array would like to be able to pass array in pthread create but right now I am getting a an error array subscript is not an integer please help me

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void * print_funtion( void* i, void* message)
{   
    printf("Thread %d: ",(int*) i);
    printf("Thread %s: ", message);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
int i;
int num = atoi(argv[1]);
//printf("%d \n", num);


for(i = 1; i <= num; i++)
{


    char *messages[] = {"Hello", "Bonjour", "Hola", "Shalom", "Namaste", "Gutan Tag", "God dag","Ola", "Salut", "Napot", "Dia"};


    //printf("%d \n", i);
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, print_funtion,(void*)i, (void*)messages[i]);
    pthread_join(tid,NULL);
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you think `printf("Thread %d: ",(int*) i); printf("Thread %d: ", messages[(int*)i]);` would do? Because it makes to sense thread or no thread. Unrelated, it is very bad practice to pass along an integer inside the void pointer, instead of pointing at one... I'd regard that as a dirty hack that can break at any point.

Comment: Change `(int*)i` to `(int)i`.

Comment: `printf("Thread %d: ", messages[(int*)i]);` is not how to print a string, use the `%s` format specifier instead, along with the other changes suggested.

Comment: this looks like a trivial/academic example, but understand from an architectural standpoint, this is a poor use of threads. The whole idea of threads is to do work in _parallel_. In your code, you are creating a single thread, then waiting for it to complete (with the `pthread_join` call), then creating the next one, etc. Serializing threads like this will gain you no speed improvements, and in fact will probably be slower than a single threaded implementation since you have introduced overhead for creating extra threads.

Comment: I have changed the code a bit now it says pthread create has to many augments

Comment: there should be 4 arguments: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems in the code and I'll point them out individually as comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// Note: In most cases, you should use (char *) for strings instead of char[XX].
// Note: You don't need to set the number of elements in the array 
// because it is automatically inferred from the initializer.
char *messages[] = {"Hello", "Bonjour", "Hola", "Shalom", "Namaste", "Gutan Tag", "God dag","Ola", "Salut", "Napot", "Dia"};

void *print_function(void *data)
{
  // The data you passed is int not a pointer to int.
  int i = (int)data;
  printf("Thread %d: \n", i);
  // You need to use %s for printing string.
  printf("Message: %s\n", messages[i]);
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int i;
  int num = atoi(argv[1]);

  // Limit the number of running threads so you don't slow down you computer (10 is already too much. It depends on the number of cores you CPU has).
  #define MAX_NUM_OF_THREADS 10
  if(num > MAX_NUM_OF_THREADS)
    num = MAX_NUM_OF_THREADS;

  // I explain why we need to store the thread ids down below.
  pthread_t thread_ids[MAX_NUM_OF_THREADS];


  for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    pthread_t tid;
    void *thread_data = (void *)(i + 1);
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, print_function, thread_data);
    thread_ids[i] = tid;
  }

  // You can't join with the thread in the previous loop because it will serialize thread creation.
  // Meaning the program will not create the next thread before the current thread finish execution.
  // Instead, you need to create all the threads first then you join to them one by one afterward.
  // And for that you need to store the thread ids for each thread in order to join with them after they are created.
  for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    pthread_join(thread_ids[i], NULL);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help the only problem with that implementation is that the threads are printing in reverse now

Comment: Of course, you can't assume the execution order between threads because they are running in parallel. That's the point.

Comment: I think your comment about 10 threads being too many is not accurate. Processes can certainly have more than 10 threads, and in linux anyway, there's no difference from an execution standpoint between a thread or a process. There are hundreds to thousands of threads of execution on a system, it's the schedulers job to manage what, when, and where they run.

Comment: @yano if you are using threads to fully use up your CPU power (expensive computation), then you will need as many threads as number of cores in your CPU. In my case I have 4 cores and a more modern user machines usually have 8 cores. From this perspective, 10 fully-utilized threads means the scheduler will waste time switching between them. However, if your are using threads as way of doing things concurrently, so that one job doesn't block the others then sure the OS can handle thousands of threads (usually those are mostly sleeping).

Comment: perhaps. I'd be surprised to learn there are hard rules within the scheduler to spread threads from a process across all the cores. Particularly if they're working on a data set that fits in cache local to 1or 2 cores, it may very well be faster to context switch rather than sync data across all the cores. But admittedly I'm no scheduler expert. These are details I wouldn't worry about unless I benchmarked my code and it was too slow. Writing code assuming a system has x number of cores isn't robust anyway, so unless OP is on a specific system, I think the number of cores is of little concern.

Comment: I don't think I completely understand your comment, but (again, I'm talking about computationally expensive tasks like compressor, video encoder, renderer) if the OS were to not distribute the threads over all the cores (which it does), say only 1 core on a 4-core CPU, then your task is only using 25% of your CPU. And 25% is in no way faster than a any number of cache misses.